# since I did something vs since I have done something

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-perfect

A sentence like

> **We've known each other since 2015**

sounds common and normal.
However, could you **explain the possible circumstances** of using a sentence with **2 Present Perfect clauses linked by "since"** of this kind:

> I've become suicidal again **since** I've worked here
>   I've been feeling down **since** you've been gone

I think I can somehow feel the meaning but I'd appreciate a native speaker's advice.
With regards,
Anabel

Answer (score 1):

"I've been feeling down since you've been gone" is odd; you shouldn't really link two present perfect clauses.  I think it would be better to say:

"Since you left, I've been feeling down."  or
"I've felt sad ever since you left."  or:
"Ever since I started working here, I've felt suicidal."

I think it's more elegant to pinpoint an event after which another event has started to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

"Since" wants a specific time or event. "You've been gone" is not an event. "You left" is an event. So, "since you left" works.

Comment: I follow your reasoning, but to my ears, "I've been feeling down since you've been gone" sounds perfectly normal as a sentence. Also, if it is true that "since" wants a specific time or event, and "you've been gone" doesn't qualify, then why are there so many songs with the phrase "since you've been gone" in them?